# Can't remove devices from provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm using a free developer account and I want to install my app on the iPhones of my workmates. Unfortunately I already put the app on some devices and my provisioning profile includes already the maximum of three devices.
Now I tried to delete the app from all from all those devices and even deleted the provisioning profiles on the devices via the XCode devices manager, so all the devices are basically clean. I also deleted the provisioning profile in Xcode itself

> (Preferences > Apple ID > View Details > Provisioning Profiles > Move
>   to trash).

XCode then recreates the profile and shows that tree devices are included in the profile

> (XCode Project > Signing > Provisioning Profile > (i) > Devices)

How can I clean the project of all those devices I connected?

Three devices linked in provisioning profile

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to do it. Apple has the restrictions on generating the provisioning profiles with allowed devices. Devices once added to available device slots consume it permanently for the entire subscription year.

You may delete the devices from provisioning profile but you can't add more devices unless your account subscription renewal is done after 1 year of time. Device once added consumes the available slot for 1 year.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know I had an account subscription. I just registered with my Apple ID for a free developer account.